# Inconsistent value received in Activity after clicking on notification

Tags: java, android, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I have encountered an issue where I'm trying to pass a value from a notification to an Activity using an intent extra. However, upon clicking on the notification and accessing the value in the Activity's onCreate method, the received value differs from the one I originally sent. I'm seeking assistance in understanding and resolving this problem.

Here's the relevant code snippet responsible for creating the notification and passing the value:

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ChatActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(ChatActivity.CURRENT_CHAT_EXTRA, chatNotifications.getTopic());
PendingIntent actionIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, AppController.CHAT_CHANNEL)
    .setContentIntent(actionIntent);
```

In the ChatActivity class, I'm retrieving the value in the onCreate method as follows:

```java
topic = getIntent().getStringExtra(CURRENT_CHAT_EXTRA);
```

The issue is that topic ends up with a different value than what was originally sent.

Why might this discrepancy be occurring and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Is the activity already open when the notification is clicked?

Comment: no, the activity is not open

Comment: it's getting opened when the user click's on the notification

Answer (score 1):

It appears that I am encountering this issue where the value received in your Activity differs from the one originally sent via the notification's intent extra. To resolve this problem, you can make use of a unique requestCode for each PendingIntent to ensure that the intent extras are received correctly.

You can modify your code as follows:

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ChatActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(ChatActivity.CURRENT_CHAT_EXTRA, chatNotifications.getTopic());

// Generate a unique requestCode based on the topic
int requestCode = chatNotifications.getTopic().hashCode();

PendingIntent actionIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, requestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, AppController.CHAT_CHANNEL)
    .setContentIntent(actionIntent);
```

By using chatNotifications.getTopic().hashCode() as the requestCode, you create a unique identifier for each PendingIntent. This ensures that each notification click will create a separate PendingIntent and the intent extra will be correctly received in your Activity's onCreate method.

Make sure to adjust your receiving code in the ChatActivity class accordingly:

```java
topic = getIntent().getStringExtra(ChatActivity.CURRENT_CHAT_EXTRA);
```

By implementing this approach, you should be able to resolve the issue of receiving different values in your Activity compared to what was originally sent from the notification.

Comment: A few of your answers appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. Thanks!

Comment: the info is from what i told for ai to write, i did it only because i am not so good in writing, and i had reviewed before posting

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  I'm supportive of using AI for grammar assistance, personally.  Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds: I don't believe it. I think ***most*** of it is raw ChatGPT output, especially the anwers.